# POSTGRES : how to call pg_bulkload inside function

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, bulkloader, bulk-load

How can I call a pg_bulkload on a text file inside a function ?

Answer (score 2):

pg_bulkload is a program, not a piece of SQL. You could start this program using pl/perlU or pl/python.

Comment: Thanks Frank for the quick response. Am a bit confused here. here is my case : I have an enormous file and I have to bulk it's lines into memory in order to perform some database updates, I have already used COPY into temporary TABLE but when i saw pg_bulkLoad i thought it wase better. Do you have any advice for me please? THANKS in advance.

Comment: COPY is very different from pg_bulkloader, there is no "better" there is only "different". You have to play with it to see if it works better for you or not. I have never used it, I really don't know.